# Create all possible AVL trees given a list of elements in Prolog

Tags: recursion, tree, prolog, binary-tree, avl-tree

Given a list of elements, return all possible balanced binary trees containing exactly the elements of that list. In our case, a valid tree is of the construct: `tree(_, left, right)`. For example:

```erlang
?- avl_tree_planter(X, [yin, yang]).
X = tree(yang, tree(yin, nil, nil), nil) ;
X = tree(yin, tree(yang, nil, nil), nil) ;
X = tree(yin, nil, tree(yang, nil, nil)) ;
X = tree(yang, nil, tree(yin, nil, nil)) ;
```

I tried to output all possible options using inorder, preorder and postorder traversals:

```erlang
abs_diff(L,R,D) :- D is L-R, L >= R.
abs_diff(L,R,D) :- D is R-L, R >= L.

height(nil,0).
height(tree(_,L,R), H) :- 
    height(L,HL), height(R,HR), 
    max_num(HL,HR,MaxH), H is MaxH + 1.

avl_tree_planter(nil,[]).
avl_tree_planter(tree(X,L,R), Xs) :-
    height(L,HL), height(R,HR),
    abs_diff(HL,HR,Diff), Diff =< 1, 
    avl_tree_planter(L,Ls), avl_tree_planter(R,Rs), 
    append(Ls,[X|Rs],Xs).     % inorder
avl_tree_planter(tree(X,L,R), Xs) :-  
    height(L,HL), height(R,HR),
    abs_diff(HL,HR,Diff), Diff =< 1,
    avl_tree_planter(L,Ls), avl_tree_planter(R,Rs), 
    append(Rs, [X], Xs1),     % postorder
    append(Ls, Xs1, Xs).  
avl_tree_planter(tree(X,L,R), Xs) :-  
    height(L,HL), height(R,HR),
    abs_diff(HL,HR,Diff), Diff =< 1,
    avl_tree_planter(L,Ls), avl_tree_planter(R,Rs), 
    append([X|Ls], Rs, Xs).   % preorder
```

In some online interpreter for the input:

```erlang
avl_tree_planter(X,[a,b]).
```

it outputs:

```erlang
X = tree(a, nil, tree(b, nil, nil))
```

twelve times and then goes to an infinite loop, and in another it loops indefinitely.

I've put a stop condition to the recursion so what am i doing wrong?

Comment: One of the problems is that your `height/2` predicate is a *generate-and-test* predicate: it first *generates* a tree, and then checks it height. That means that eventually the predicate will keep proposing trees of heights that all fail, but thus get stuck in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that this gets stuc in an infinte loop is because your `height/2` uses a *generate-and-test* approach: it first constructs a tree, and then it validates if the height matches the required height. But as the trees grow bigger and bigger, eventually your check will start to reject these trees, but there is no way to tell your predicate to stop proposing new trees.

We can construct AVL trees where each node has a difference of at most one as follows:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

height(nil, 0).
height(tree(_, L, R), H) :-
    H #> 0,
    H1 #= H-1,
    H2 #= H-2,
    (
        (height(L, H1), height(R, H1));
        (height(L, H1), height(R, H2));
        (height(L, H2), height(R, H1))
    ).
```

Now we thus can generate trees, and "tag" the nodes of these trees with extra elements. It might help to make a more generic predicate `height/3` that exports a list of variables:

```
height(T, H, N) :-
    height(T, H, N, []).

height(nil, 0, N, N).
height(tree(X, L, R), H, [X|Ni], No) :-
    H #> 0,
    H1 #= H-1,
    H2 #= H-2,
    (
        (height(L, H1, Ni, Nt), height(R, H1, Nt, No));
        (height(L, H1, Ni, Nt), height(R, H2, Nt, No));
        (height(L, H2, Ni, Nt), height(R, H1, Nt, No))
    ).
```

For example:

```
?- height(T, 2, N).
T = tree(_622, tree(_642, nil, nil), tree(_662, nil, nil)),
N = [_622, _642, _662] ;
T = tree(_622, tree(_642, nil, nil), nil),
N = [_622, _642] ;
T = tree(_622, nil, tree(_642, nil, nil)),
N = [_622, _642] ;
false.
```

I leave it as an exercise to tag the tree with the elements in the list.